# Storing dollar amounts in MySQL: INT vs LONG vs BIGINT

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, long-integer, bigint

I am constructing a database where I need to store currency values. I am storing the currency values as cents ($100.00 = 10000 ¢). So, I decided against using `INT` to store the currency values (a signed int is limited to storing `$21,474,836.48`).

I saw that MySQL has two other similar types: `BIGINT` and `LONG`.

After researching and not being able to figure out the difference, I made an arbitrary decision to use `BIGINT`. But then when I went to write the PreparedStatement:

```
int id = ...;
BigInteger amount = ...;

String sql = "insert into transaction(id, amount) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInt(1, id);
if(amount == null)
    pstmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
else
    pstmt.setBigInteger(2, amount); // <---- This method does not exist
```

There is no `PreparedStatement::setBigInt()` method. The only `PreparedStatement` methods that exist are `setInt()`, `setLong()`, and `setBigDecimal`.

So, then I reversed my decision and decided to use `LONG` instead, but when I went to write the same code, I noticed this:

```
int id = ...;
BigInteger amount = ...;

String sql = "insert into transaction(id, amount) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInt(1, id);
if(amount == null)
    pstmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.LONG); // <---- This java.sql.Type does not exist
else
    pstmt.setLong(2, amount.longValue());
```

So the `PreparedStatement` does not have a `setBigInt` (or `setBigInteger`) method, and the `java.sql.Types` package does not contain a `LONG` enum.

The questions are:

1. What is the difference between `BIGINT` and `LONG` on the MySQL level? Which is more ideal for storing currencies?
2. What would happen if I use `PreparedStatement::setLong` on a `BIGINT` column?
3. That also begs the question, what happens if I use `PreparedStatement::setBigDecimal` on a `BIGINT` column?

EDIT/UPDATE:

My apologies for the bad question. I had no idea that MySQL doesn't even have `LONG` datatypes. In part because the data modeler I am using to construct my database (MySQL's own: MySQL Workbench) does allow you to set `LONG` as a datatype. However, when you forward engineer the database, it changes the `LONG` to `BIGINT`.

[image: picture from MySQL Workbench datamodeler which I'm using to assist the construction of my DB]

(picture from MySQL Workbench datamodeler which I'm using to assist the construction of my DB).

Comment: I would use DECIMAL not an INT-type, see [manual, Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: `long` is a float value. do not store non-floating values in it. use bigint. it's a 64bit value and you're unlikely to ever be dealing with dollar/cent values that could exceed 2^64

Comment: @VMai, which `PreparedStatement` method would you, then, use to set a `DECIMAL` type?

Comment: BigDecimal for Decimal.

Comment: @MarcB: What are you talking about?  `long` is an integer type in  every language I've ever come across; indeed, it is an 8-byte integer in Java.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer#Long_integer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. > What is the difference between `BIGINT` and `LONG` on the MySQL level?

   - [`java.sql.Types.BIGINT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#BIGINT) is defined as:

     > The constant in the Java programming language, sometimes referred to as a type code, that identifies the generic SQL type `BIGINT`.

     Under [Integer Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html), the MySQL manual documents that its `BIGINT` datatype is an 8-byte (i.e. 64-bit) integer.  The Java [primitive datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `long` (and its associated wrapper class [`java.lang.Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)) also represents an 8-byte integer.

     Consequently, as documented under [Mapping SQL and Java Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#1012177):

     > The JDBC type `BIGINT` represents a 64-bit signed integer value between `-9223372036854775808` and `9223372036854775807`.
     >
     > ```
     > [ deletia — outdated ]
     > ```
     >
     > The recommended Java mapping for the `BIGINT` type is as a Java `long`.
   - There is no `LONG` constant within [`java.sql.Types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html), nor does MySQL have a `LONG` datatype.

   > Which is more ideal for storing currencies?

   Neither.  Store the dollar amount as a discrete decimal value using the [`NUMERIC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fixed-point-types.html) fixed-point datatype.  If you insist on storing the cent amount in an integer type, the "correct" answer depends merely on the anticipated range of values that you wish to support.
2. > What would happen if I use `PreparedStatement::setLong` on a `BIGINT` column?

   That is exactly how one *should* set the value of a `BIGINT` parameter.  As documented under [`java.sql.PreparedStatement::setLong(int, long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong%28int%2c%20long%29):

   > The driver converts this to an SQL `BIGINT` value when it sends it to the database.
3. > That also begs the question, what happens if I use `PreparedStatement::setBigDecimal` on a `BIGINT` column?

   As documented under [`java.sql.PreparedStatement::setBigDecimal(int, java.math.BigDecimal)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBigDecimal%28int%2c%20java.math.BigDecimal%29):

   > The driver converts this to an SQL `NUMERIC` value when it sends it to the database.

   So, Java will send your value to MySQL as a [`NUMERIC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fixed-point-types.html) (fixed-point decimal) datatype.  MySQL will then perform type conversion as described under [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html): e.g. if you are simply storing the value in a `BIGINT` column, the value will be cast to a `BIGINT` for storage.  Provided that the value is in range for a `BIGINT`, you shouldn't notice any ill-effect (except loss of the fractional part).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I edited the question to show why I was under the impression that MySQL even had `LONG` datatypes. I've learned so much by this question / your answer. Hopefully the question serves a purpose in posterity.